# Como atualizar a página sem reenviar informações para o banco de dados em php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, mysqli

Estou trabalhando em um sistema de mensagem simples, e ele até que funciona, porém sempre que é dado um refresh na página são reenviadas ao banco de dados as informações do último insert. E se não foi preenchido nada, e foi dado refresh ele simplesmente envia um valor vazio pro banco de dados, assim como se sair da página e voltar para a mesma são enviados os valores vazios da mesma forma. Eu pesquisei bastante no google e testei várias coisas, porém nada funcionou até agora, eu achei algumas que tentavam anular dados replicados, porém nesse caso eu gostaria que fosse enviado duplicado de qualquer forma se for feito pelo submit pelo usuário. Alguém sabe se tem como diferenciar o submit do refresh?

Coloquei uma imagem demonstrando a página e a mensagem de erro que aparece quando é dado F5, isso não é exclusivo do firefox. As mensagens em branco com nome em branco são do que eu falei antes.

Segue o código:

Danilo Macedo Bakun

Home

Currículo

Contato

Comentarios

```
    <div id="tudo">
        <form id="formulario" action="comentarios.php" method="POST">
            <h1>Nome:</h1>
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="Nome" required><br>
            <h1>Mensagem: </h1><br>
            <textarea  id="mensagem" name="Mensagem" required></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
        </form>

        <?php
            $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','teste') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');

            if (isset($_POST['Nome']) === true) 
            {
                $nome = $_POST['Nome'];
            } else {
                $nome = false;
            }

            if (isset($_POST['Mensagem']) === true) 
            {
                $mensagem = $_POST['Mensagem'];
            } else {
                $mensagem = false;
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO mensagem VALUES ('$nome', '$mensagem')";
            mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");


            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM mensagem";
            $sqlc = mysqli_query($strcon,$consulta) or die("Erro ao tentar consultar registro");
            while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlc)) 
            { 
                echo "<h1>-----------------------------------------</h1><br>"; 
                echo "<h1>Nome: ".$aux["nome"]."</h1><br>";
                echo "<h1>Mensagem:".$aux["mensagem"]."</h1><br>";
            }

            mysqli_close($strcon);
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer de algumas maneiras:

- Fazer post do formulário por ajax e limpar os campos (por javascript). Desse jeito, quando o usuário apertar F5, vai somente recarregar a página ao invés de reenviar os dados.
- Fazer post no formulário submetendo o FORM para outra página PHP. Quando a outra página PHP terminar de inserir no banco, você pode redirecionar para a página que tem seu formulário.

> Segue sugestão de código para a segunda opção:

seu_formulario_html.php

```
<div id="tudo">
        <form id="formulario" action="trata_comentarios.php" method="POST">
            <h1>Nome:</h1>
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="Nome" required><br>
            <h1>Mensagem: </h1><br>
            <textarea  id="mensagem" name="Mensagem" required></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

trata_comentarios.php

```
<?php
            $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','teste') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');

            if (isset($_POST['Nome']) === true) 
            {
                $nome = $_POST['Nome'];
            } else {
                $nome = false;
            }

            if (isset($_POST['Mensagem']) === true) 
            {
                $mensagem = $_POST['Mensagem'];
            } else {
                $mensagem = false;
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO mensagem VALUES ('$nome', '$mensagem')";
            mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");

            header("Location:/seu_formulario_html.php");
            exit;
        ?>
```

Se vc observar, eu apaguei aquele SELECT que vc fez. 
Para listar as mensagens, você pode colocar esse SELECT no mesmo PHP do seu formulário.

Comment: Consegui resolver usando outra página php, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais fácil é separar seu HTML do seu PHP, basta criar uma pagina por exemplo recebe.php e colocar o action do formulário apontando pra essa página, quando salvar redireciona pra página do formulário.

Comment: Consegui resolver usando outra página php, muito obrigado pela ajuda.